# finding data column wise in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a Employee class, i am retriving employee data using nhibernate.It gives 
complete column.(eq. sql - Select * ). But, if i want to have slected column (like EmployeeName and EmployeeID only),then i need to create a class with these two properties(e.g.Empl class).and using AliasToBeanResultTransformer i.e. Projection i can retrive. I want to know that is there any way in nhibernate (without creating sub classes(Empl class), or without hard coding hql query)so that i can retrive specific column values...

```
class Employee
{     
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
  public int ResidingInCountryId { get; set; }
  public virtual Country ResidenceCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to project a few columns from a query then you can either

a) use a DTO although you mentioned you don't like this for some reason

b) if you `REALLY` want a list of anonymous objects then simply omit the result transformer which will result in a list of anonymous objects with the projected values. This would be sufficient for databinding.

Also you do not need to use just HQL for projectons, you can use Criteria, QueryOver or NH Linq.

Comment: @ Rippo Thanks for ur response   I am trying to create a generic method..so that i need to pass only the main class instance and list of column names. e.g.  `public IList<S> GetListByCriteriaQuery<T,S>()` T is the main class and S is the Sub class(any combination of columns of T class).It is not possible to create classes of each combination of columns as it is not fixed.I looked all three suggestion and i find that i need to hard code the column name which i dont want to do..Sry due to lack of space i m not able to put my complete logic.are u able to understand me or i need to discuss more.

Comment: I implemeted Criteria and able to return list of Array objects. Thanks